# What Python urrlib user_agent string to use?

Tags: python, html, urllib

I'm trying to read the HTML from a website using urllib with Python 3.4 and am encountering a problem.

I am trying to download a page that has the conjugation for the Italian verb "essere". There are two sources I can access: wordreference.com and verbix.com.

Using this code, I can successfully get the html from wordreference.com:

```
url = 'http://www.wordreference.com//conj//ItVerbs.aspx?v=essere'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name' : 'John',
          'location' : 'USA',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent}

data  = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   verbHTMLStr = response.read()
   print(verbHTMLStr)
```

If I change the URL to the access the Verbix.com website to

```
url = 'http://www.verbix.com//webverbix//Italian//essere.html'
```

the html returned is for www.verbix.com/languages

Both URL strings return the expected pages when copied into a browser's address bar.

It seems to me that the Verbix site wants to see something else as user_agent, but I cannot figure out what it wants. I've tried a number of different user_agent strings and all return the same incorrect page.

Answer (score 1):

To me below is working!

```
import urllib

res=urllib.urlopen('http://www.verbix.com//webverbix//Italian//essere.html').read()
print res
```

It prints-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- #BeginTemplate "/Templates/verbtable_pure.dwt" -->
<!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<title>
Italian
verb
essere
conjugated in all tenses.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Language,verb,Italian,essere,conjugation,conjugate">
<meta name="description" content="Italian verb essere conjugated in all tenses.">
<meta name="author" content="Verbix">
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/pure/pure-min.css">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/combo/1.18.13?/css/layouts/side-menu-old-ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/misc-pure/side-menu-verb.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/pure/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/pure/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-61929-7']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<!-- Begin Cookie Consent plugin by Silktide - http://silktide.com/cookieconsent -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"We use cookies to personalize content and ads to users, providing features for social media and analyze our traffic. We will forward information about your use of our website to social media and advertising and research companies that we work with.","dismiss":"Got it!","learnMore":"More info","link":"http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/termsofuse.html","theme":"dark-top"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cc.silktide.com/cookieconsent.latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- End Cookie Consent plugin -->
<!-- #BeginEditable "Head" --><!-- #EndEditable -->

</head>


<body>


<div id="layout"> 
  <!-- Menu toggle --> 
  <a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link"> 
  <!-- Hamburger icon --> 
  <span></span> </a> 
  <div id="menu"> <a href="/"><img src="/system/html5/top_left.png"/> </a> 
    <div class="pure-menu"> <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="/languages">Online</a> 
      <ul class="pure-menu-list"> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/languages" class="pure-menu-link">Verb Conjugator</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/translate/" class="pure-menu-link">Verb Translation</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/find-verb/" class="pure-menu-link">Find Verb</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/games/" class="pure-menu-link">Games</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/maps/" class="pure-menu-link">Language Maps</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="/windowsverbix/">Windows</a> 
      <ul class="pure-menu-list"> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/windowsverbix/" class="pure-menu-link">Verbix for Windows</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/download/" class="pure-menu-link">Download</a></li> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/store/" class="pure-menu-link">Store</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="/wizard/">For Webmasters</a> 
      <ul class="pure-menu-list"> 
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="/wizard/" class="pure-menu-link">Your Own Conjugator</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="/webverbix/termsofuse.html">About ...</a> </div> 
  </div> 
  <div id="main"> 
    <div class="header"> 
      <h1> 
        Italian 
        :
        essere 
      </h1> 
      <h2> 
        Italian 
        verb ' 
        essere 
        ' conjugated in all tenses</h2> 
    </div> 
    <div class="advertising"> 
      <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> 
      <!-- MainLeftReactive --> 
      <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3716807887832772"
     data-ad-slot="9886612560"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins> 
      <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> 
    </div> 
    <div class="verbcontent"> 
      <p><a href="http://www.verbix.com/languages/italian.shtml" rel="prev">Conjugate another
        Italian 
        verb</a> 
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --> 
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_pub="verbix";</script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {services_exclude: 'print',data_ga_property: 'UA-61929-7', data_track_clickback: true}</script> 
        <a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=20" onMouseOver="return addthis_open(this, '', '[URL]', '[TITLE]')" onMouseOut="addthis_close()" onClick="return addthis_sendto()"><img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/lg-share-en.gif" width="125" height="16" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0"/></a> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/200/addthis_widget.js"></script> 
        <!-- AddThis Button END --> 
      </p> 

      <div class="pure-g verbtable"> <!-- #BeginEditable "Full_width_text" --> 
        <div class="pure-u-1-1"> 
          <h2>Nominal Forms</h2> 
          <div class="pure-g"> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-3"> 
              <p><b>Infinito:<br>Participio presente:<br>Gerundio:<br>Participio passato:</b></p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-3"> 
              <p><span class="normal">essere</span><br>
<span class="normal">essente</span><br>
<span class="normal">essendo</span><br>
<span class="irregular">stato</span><br>
</p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-3"> 
              <p> 
                <span class="normal">avere stato</span><br>


                <span class="normal">avendo stato</span><br>

                <span class="normal">avente stato</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-lg-1-2"> 
          <h2>Indicativo</h2> 
          <div class="pure-g"> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Presente</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sono</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sei</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">&egrave;</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">siamo</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">siete</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sono</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Passato prossimo</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">ho stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">hai stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">ha stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">abbiamo stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avete stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">hanno stato</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Imperfetto</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">ero</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">eri</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">era</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">eravamo</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">eravate</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">erano</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Trapassato prossimo</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avevo stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avevi stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">aveva stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avevamo stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avevate stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avevano stato</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Futuro</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sar&ograve;</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sarai</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sar&agrave;</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">saremo</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">sarete</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">saranno</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Futuro anteriore</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avr&ograve; stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avrai stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avr&agrave; stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avremo stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avrete stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avranno stato</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Passato remoto</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">fui</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">fosti</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">fu</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">fummo</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">foste</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="irregular">furono</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Trapassato remoto</h3> 
              <p> 
                <font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">io</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">ebbi stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">tu</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avesti stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">lui</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">ebbe stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">noi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">avemmo stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">voi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">aveste stato</span><br>
<font color=#007F00 face=Courier><span class="normal">loro</span>&nbsp;</font><span class="normal">ebbero stato</span><br>

              </p> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-lg-1-2"> 
          <h2>Congiuntivo</h2> 
          <div class="pure-g"> 
            <div class="pure-u-1-2"> 
              <h3>Presente</h3> ...........................
```

Comment: This does, indeed, work when run with Python 2.7, but gives  this error when run with 3.4: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' Clearly there is a difference in the libraries of the two versions that I would like to understand.

Comment: Whoops - forgot to thank SIslam for his answer...thank you!